# Eclipse can't see objects in the array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

My problem is very strange for me and concerns java language. I created interface and 2 classes. In the interface I created 2 object's: public static final MyInterface obA and obB. And in the each of classes I created array which stores these objects. If I want to display array of first class, I can't see any objects. In second class i see only firts object. My code:

```
public class ROpole implements IDevices {

private static IDevices rOpole = IDevices.rOpole;
private static IDevices rGdańsk = IDevices.rGdańsk;

private IDevices [] connectedWith = {rGdańsk, null};

...

}

public class RGdańsk implements IDevices {

private static IDevices rOpole = IDevices.rOpole;
private static IDevices rGdańsk = IDevices.rGdańsk;

private IDevices [] connectedWith = {rOpole, null, null};

...

}

public interface IDevices {

public static final IDevices rOpole = new ROpole();
public static final IDevices rGdańsk = new RGdańsk();

...

}
```

My result if I want to display objects: 
rOpole: Connected with: null, null. 
rGdańsk: Connected with: Model.ROpole@74a14482, null, null.

I don't know why object's are invisible in these arrays.

My method which display a objects:

```
public String getInfoAboutDevice() {
    String informationsAboutDevice = "";
    informationsAboutDevice += "Connected with: ";

    for(int count = 0; count < connectedWith.length; count++) {
        if(count == interfaces.length - 1) informationsAboutDevice += connectedWith[count] + ".";
        else informationsAboutDevice += connectedWith[count] + ", ";
    }

    informationsAboutDevice += "\n";

    return informationsAboutDevice;
}
```

Comment: I have a method which display the objects in the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with static initialization order. When `IDevices` is loaded, first its `rOpole` static field will be instantiated, and then `rGdańsk`. However, that means the `ROpole` constructor will run before `IDevices.rGdańsk` has even been assigned, so there is no way it could pick up the correct reference.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use inheritance of static fields in interfaces? 
The ones declared final are not going to change after instantiation.

So in order to instantiate `ROpole` or `RGdańsk` the JVM needs to resolve `IDevices`.

`IDevices` must initialize final field `IDevices.rOpole`; at this time, the final field `IDevices.rGdańsk` is `null`.

An object of type `ROpole` is created and it's `connectedWith` array is filled with the `null` reference to `IDevices.rGdańsk`

Then `IDevices` must initialize final field `IDevices.rGdańsk`; At this time the `IDevices.rOpole` is referencing to the `ROpole` object just created, thus `IDevices.rGdańsk` field `connectedWith` contains: `Model.ROpole@74a14482`

You need to review your design: [Java Interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_%28Java%29) are intended to define type and (in java 8) behavior. You should not use them to inherit the state, unless it is a static state and, thus, strictly related to the type and shared among all instances of the type.

Comment: I used the Singleton method to initialize a rOpole and rGdańsk object's, but problem is not solved.